# Why " onclick='submit()' " does not validate the form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

Why "**`<button onclick="submit()"> Submit</button>`**" don't work for validations?

and why "**`<input type="submit" value="submit">`**" works?

```
 <form action="#" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="val" required><br>
        <button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: Why duplicate the submit buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is going to try to call a javascript function called `submit`. I assume you don't have such a function.

If you wanted to use javascript to submit the form, you would create a submit function like so:

```
function submit() {
    document.getElementById("form_ID").submit();
}
```

And you'd have to give your form an ID. I've used `form_ID` in the function, but you can choose something else.

Comment: Could also just use `this.form.submit()` in the button's `onclick` handler